# Body looks much bigger than the content and white space appear in right side of web page

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the CSS when I tried to put the image in the centre of the page and align-items: centre, huge white space appears on the right side of the page, and when I tried to change the postilion of the image, the login appears down of the first image.
I attached the HTML and CSS
[image]
[image]

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.img {
    display: inline;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}
.img img {
    width: 500px;
}
.loginContent {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: center;
    grid-gap: 7rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="learning.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="loginContent">
        <form action="v2.html">
            <img id="avatar" src="avatar.svg">
            <h2 class="title">Welcome</h2>
               
            <div class="input-div one">
                  <div class="i"></div> 
                  <div class="div">
                          <h5>Username</h5>
                          <input type="text" class="input">
                  </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="input-div pass">
                <div class="i"> </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Password</h5>
                    <input type="password" class="input">
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn" value="Login">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your container is a flexbox or grid, I'm pretty sure that adding `display: inline-block;` to your `.loginContent` and `.img` divs is superfluous.

Comment: Why have you got `justify-content` and `align-items` properties on your `.loginContent` and `.img` classes? Those aren't flexboxes, what are those properties accomplishing?

Comment: Why are you previewing the site at 3050px wide!?

Comment: oK, Thanks a lot for the note. But even if I delete that still, the white space appears!

Comment: I am here trying to justify-content in a different way. I preview like this Because the contents of the page appear at the end.

Comment: It appears to work for me if I change the container to just 'grid' (not inline grid) and `add margin: 0 auto;` to `.container`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will adjust all the settings according to your recommendation. If the image is SVG causing any problems?

Comment: You pretty much always need to specifically target svg in your css and explicitly set width and height (often leaving one as 'auto'), otherwise svg's sizes can go haywire.

Comment: I see, and that is exactly what I did. Thank you a lot for response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to turn off the [Toggle Device Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ILb.png) because when I run and manipulate your code, there isn't any "huge white space appears on the right side of the page".

Comment: Yes right it looks ok when I turn it off, but I need to test it on different devices.